# TikTok API authorization process

Tags: authorization, tiktok, tiktok-api

TikTok's authorization process for the Accounts API involves sending the authorization URL to the customer. Problem is that the URL has a random ID as a parameter that is unique for every login and the only way to generate it seems to be by loading the Application dashboard inside the browser. Is there a way to do it more progrematically or fetch/generate it some other way?

For the moment no good solution comes to mind.